# Adding Multiple Folder Names From Directory To OptionMenu Python

Tags: python, tkinter, path, directory, optionmenu

I am trying to add multiple folder names to an options menu. The code below adds only one folder name to the list but I want to add all folder names in the directory.

```
var = StringVar()
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\mhoban')
all_subdirs = [d for d in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(d)]
for dirs in all_subdirs:
    dir = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\mhoban', dirs)
    os.chdir(dir)
    current = os.getcwd()
    new = str(current).split("\\")[3]

opt1 = OptionMenu(app, var, new)
opt1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
opt1.configure(width = 40, bg = "White")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a list of menu options and then unpack it where you're passing `new` at the moment:

```
options = []
for dirs in all_subdirs:
    ...  # same
    options.append(str(current).split("\\")[3])
```

Unpacking `options`:

```
opt1 = OptionMenu(app, var, *options)
```

Note: `options` will be the same as `all_subdirs`, so your processing doesn't seem to achieve anything. Just use `all_subdirs` instead.

Comment: Im getting a sythax error on this line "opt1 = OptionMenu(app, var, *options)"

Comment: @Peter Wood, count your parentheses, you're missed one. And `options` list is a same as `all_subdirs` so OP can unpack it aswell without iteration?

Comment: @Peter Wood, yeah, no problem. But again, i think it worth to mention in your answer that `all_subdirs` is already a list with dir-names, so there's no need in another list at all. `opt1 = OptionMenu(app, var, *all_subdirs)`